# Makefile to move .o files to Different Directory

Tags: c, makefile, vpath

I have source code in one directory and have a makefile in a different directory. I am able to compile the code using the make system's vpath mechanism. The .o files are being created in the same folder where the makefile is. But I want to move those .o files to a different directory called `obj`. I tried the following:

```
vpath %.o obj
```

However, they are still being created in the same folder as the makefile. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Here are some highlighted lines of the makefile:

```
PATH_TO_OBJ:- ../obj
SRC :- .c files
OBJS :- $(SRC:.c = .o)
.c.o = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c 
exe: cc $(LFLAGS) -o $(PATH_TO_OBJ) $(SRC).
```

After this also, .o file is creating in same folder of Makefile. Not moving to obj

Comment: You look at this page, it should solve your problem : http://mad-scientist.net/make/vpath.html . If you really want to understand your error, please post a minimal working example of your Makefile

Comment: You are missing a `/` between `$(PATH_TO_OBJ)` and `$(SRC)`. Also there must be not spaces between them. By the way you should format your code in question to make it readable for others.

Answer (score 5):

`-o` option defines where to save the output file, produced by a gcc compiler.

```
gcc main.c -c -o path/to/object/files/main.o
```

Comment: still not getting. hre is my makefile

Comment: You are missing a `/` between `$(PATH_TO_OBJ)` and `$(SRC)`. Also there must be not spaces between them.

Answer (score 3):

Make's `VPATH` is only for finding source files.  The placement of object files is up to the thing that is building them.  There's a nice description at http://mad-scientist.net/make/vpath.html (I see someone beat me to posting this in a comment).

The *BSD build systems use variants of `make` that can place object files (and other generated files, including C sources from lex and yacc variants) in `/usr/obj` automatically.  If you have access to that version of `make`, that will likely be a good way to deal with whatever underlying problem you are trying to solve.